# Загрузка файлов с поддомена php

Tags: php, upload

Есть панель управления которая находится на поддомене dashboard.site.com.

Возникла задача загружать файлы с панели управления на основной домен.

То-есть задача следующая:

С панели управления по адресу dashboard.site.com загрузить файлы в папку sources на домен site.com.

Интересует не сама загрузка а получить доступ и правильный путь к директории

Прошу помощи в реализации данной задачи. Подскажите метод реализации.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "получить доступ и правильный путь к директории"? Вы ходите из панели загружать файлы в папку `site.com/sources`?

Comment: Вы описали абстрактную задачу, но какой вопрос? С какой проблемой вы столкнулись?

Answer (score 0):

Не получится у Вас загрузить напрямую - межскриптовые протоколы безопасности не позволят.
Что можно сделать - через скрипт загружать стандартным методом:

```
<form action="http://domain-другой-куда-нужно.com/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <!-- .. -->
</form>
```

Или - через скрипт на целевом домене, по типу файлового менеджера, с использованием его механизма трансферта, реализовать автоотправку по путям - то есть, вы открываете файловый менеджер на сайте(скрипт, не с хостинга) для подгрузки файлов с компа, например - меняете все действия с ручного на авто.

Есть варианты, если оба на одном сервере и вы администратор...

Answer (score 0):

Все получится если сайты находятся на одном сервере, путь к папке (например: /upload) для загрузки в админке пишите так:
/home/юзер/public_html/upload и все проблемы...